# Is livy available for dse versin 6.04

Tags: datastax-enterprise, livy

Hi I am trying to install livy in dse cluster version 6.0.4. I have copied the livy foder in dse and trying to execute livy server:

```
dse exec livy-server
```

But getting error

```
unknown command exec
```

I have checked the dse documentation for this version and livy is not listed.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/3rdpartysoftware/dse604.html

I just want to know is there any other to install livy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that something wrong in your setup, maybe somebody re-defined the `dse` command?

I just checked the whole process on DSE 6.0.7, installed from packages on CentOS 7.3:

```sh
wget https://www-us.apache.org/dist/incubator/livy/0.6.0-incubating/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin.zip
unzip apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin.zip
cd apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/
dse exec bin/livy-server
```

and got

```
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Welcome to
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:       ____              __
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.3.4
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:       /_/
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:
19/08/19 07:13:13 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Using Scala version 2.11.8, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_201
...
19/08/19 07:13:15 INFO server.Server: Started @4379ms
19/08/19 07:13:15 INFO server.WebServer: Starting server on http://XXXXXXXXX:8998
```

Please check the location of the `dse` command, and if it's from DSE itself. Also, you don't need to copy Livy to DSE directory.

And it's strongly recommended to upgrade to latest DSE 6.0 - there were some critical problems in 6.0.4, that were fixed in 6.0.5 and later versions.